# SQL - How to work with columns mapping to different data?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with two columns, and both columns are foreign keys to another table on an Oracle database.

```
Table: one
----------------------------------------
| var            |  var                |
----------------------------------------
| 5              |  10                 |
| 12             |  8                  |
----------------------------------------
```

I'm able to select both columns just by doing:

```
select var, val
from one
```

Then there's this other table:

```
Table: two
----------------------------------------
| s              |  data               |
----------------------------------------
| 5              |  hello              |
| 10             |  world              |
| 12             |  one                |
| 8              |  two                |
----------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to transform the table one with all the data mapping from s to var, such that:

```
----------------------------------------
| val            |  var                |
----------------------------------------
| hello          |  world              |
| one            |  two                |
----------------------------------------
```

Hence I've tried to use this query:

```
select two.data as var_name, two.data as val_name
from (
      select var as one_var, val as one_val
      from one
     ), two
where one_var = two.s
or one_val = two.s
```

But this won't work, because it will place the transformed table with both data from one_var, and one_val into var_name, because of the "or". I'm trying to work the data as a tuple, and I'm not sure how to do it.

Can anyone give me a pointer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the two table twice.

```
SELECT T2.data as var_name, T1.data as val_name
FROM one O
INNER JOIN two T1
    ON O.var = T1.s
INNER JOIN two T2
    ON O.val = T2.s
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to see the mapped result, you can use

```
select two_a.data as val, two_b.data as var
from one
inner join two as two_a on two_a.s = one.var
inner join two as two_b on two_b.s = one.val
```